# Delphi Firemonkey TListBox drag and drop

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, firemonkey, delphi-xe3, firemonkey-fm2

I have a ListBox that I need to contain list of files. I need functionality for user to select one or multiple files and than to drag files and drop them on the ListBox. When files are dropped, Items are created with a file names. This works fine, but the problem is, when I drag over and drop file on a dynamically created Item inside ListBox, file icon remains drawn on a desktop as a "ghost". Please check following screenshots for more details:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

This "sample.txt" icon remains on desktop. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

This is the code used for drag and drop operation:

```
procedure TTestForm.FileListBoxDragDrop(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
  const Point: TPointF);
var
  i: integer;
  item: TListBoxItem;
begin
  try
    FileListBox.BeginUpdate;
    for i := Low(Data.Files) to High(Data.Files) do begin
      Item := TListBoxItem.Create(Self);
      Item.Text := ExtractFileName(Data.Files[i]);
      Item.Parent := FileListBox;
    end;
  finally
    FileListBox.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TTestForm.FileListBoxDragOver(Sender: TObject; const Data: TDragObject;
  const Point: TPointF; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := True;
end;
```